# schedule a trigger every minute, if job still running then standby and wait for the next trigger

Tags: quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

I need to schedule a trigger to fire every minute, next minute if the job is still running the trigger should not fire and should wait another minute to check, if job has finished the trigger should fire
Thanks

Comment: you didn't say what language and tools you're using. Java? C#? What version? What precision do you need? Is it ok if the schedule is a couple seconds off, or does it have to be precise like a clock?

Answer (score 17):

In Quartz 2, you'll want to use the `DisallowConcurrentExecution` attribute on your job class. Then make sure that you set up a key using something similar to `TriggerBuilder.Create().WithIdentity( "SomeTriggerKey" )` as `DisallowConcurrentExecution` uses it to determine if your job is already running.

```
[DisallowConcurrentExecution]
public class MyJob : IJob
{
 ...
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I didnt find any thing about monitor.enter or something like that, thanks any way
the other answer is that the job should implement the 'StatefulJob' interface. As a StatefulJob, another instance will not run as long as one is already running
thanks again

Comment: Please note Ian's answer, in quartz.net 2.0 you should use DisallowConcurrentExecution  instead of IStatefulJob which is obsolete

Answer (score 2):

IStatefulJob is the key here. Creating own locking mechanisms may cause problems with the scheduler as you are then taking part in the threading.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Quartz.NET, you can do something like this in your Execute method:

```
object execution_lock = new object();

public void Execute(JobExecutionContext context) {
    if (!Monitor.TryEnter(execution_lock, 1)) {
        return,
    }

    // do work

    Monitor.Exit(execution_lock);
}
```

I pull this off the top of my head, maybe some names are wrong, but that's the idea: lock on some object while you're executing, and if upon execution the lock is on, then a previous job is still running and you simply `return;`

EDIT: the Monitor class is in the System.Threading namespace

Answer (score 0):

If you are using spring quartz integration, you can specify the 'concurrent' property to 'false' from MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean

```
 <bean id="positionFeedFileProcessorJobDetail" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean">
        <property name="targetObject" ref="xxxx" />
        <property name="targetMethod" value="xxxx" />
        <property name="concurrent" value="false" /> <!-- This will not run the job if the previous method is not yet finished -->
    </bean>
```